Is it possible to add scroll bar to half part of table-angular
In table I want scroll bar to last 2 columns so that we can scroll next part.
is it possible to add that in angular.
I am able to add scroll to entire table but what I actually want is I want scroll bar to last two columns only
wanted to add scroll bar to half part of table,
for clarity refer image that i have shared

What version of angular are you using? You have used both old and new Angular tags (angularjs is for versions before 2.0). Also, are you using any style or component libraries? Need more information to answer your question. Please consider creating an MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

You can use sticky columns if you want certain columns to always be in view and the rest to be scrollable: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-sticky-columns

check image down scroll which is in blue color showing for half part of table ....if i use sticky it stick the first column but we can see scrollbar to entire table...i am not writting any css code to show that scroll its default scroll view
